# Pointer arithmetic with a void pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I was wondering if theres a better way instead of casting a void pointer to `uint8_t`, then do arithmetic based on an offset, then cast it to `uint32_t`, then dereference it to get a 4byte value at that exact offset.

```
void * foo = malloc(1024);
uint32_t myVar;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  myVar = *((uint32_t*)((uint8_t *) foo + nOffset));
  nOffset += 100;
}
```

Comment: Off-topic: `i < 10` makes more sense than `i> 10` here.

Comment: For a slight improvement, use `char` instead of `uint8_t`. It's not the bit-width you're concerned with here, but the element size of the pointer. `sizeof(char)` is 1, by definition.

Comment: @luserdroog Unless the data is actually characters, it's makes more sence to use `uint8_t`. While it will be no difference on just about all modern platforms, having it as the generic `uint8_t` gives some semantic hints when reading the code.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Agree-ish. It's precisely those semantic hints that I'm worried about. It doesn't convey (to me) any actual meaning. I just stare at it and wonder why it isn't `char`.

Comment: Since the code generally has undefined behavior, is it really worth belabouring which undefined behaviour looks prettiest?

Comment: @KerrekSB Actually I'm just wondering about the line with the pointer aritmetic and if there's a smoother way to do this than cast twice and then dereference?

Comment: Start with `unsigned char * foo = malloc(1024);`?

Comment: Okay, that was just an example. My actual `void* data` is passed somewhereelse and I have no influence on it. But i could actually just create a new `unsigned char* bar = (unsigned char*) foo` to work with! thanks!

Comment: @tzippy: You don't need to cast the pointer. Void pointers are implicitly convertible to object pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You would better simply stay within one "domain" of pointer arithmetic.

You should do 
    uint32_t * foo = malloc(1024);

and then either

```
myVar = foo + nOffset / sizeof(*foo);
nOffset += 100;
```

or

```
myVar = foo + nOffset;
nOffset += 100 / sizeof(*foo);
```

for advancing by 100 bytes at each step.